# How to put public key in sftp server from linux machine?

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp

I have a sftp server on linux machine A and I want to access it via password-less authentication to connect from machine B. So I created a ssh key pair on machine B but I'm not sure how to copy that pub-key to the sftp server. Both machines are centos7 machines. Can someone please shed some light on how to copy a file to the sftp server with a command or script that will allow password-less authentication to the sftp server (server A)?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Arun, in order for public-key/private-key authorization to work on Linux, there are a few formalities regarding the keys that need to be observed. Primarily the permissions and the file that contains the public key from Server B on Server A.

First on Server B, generate your public and private keys with, e.g. `ssh-keygen -t rsa`. This will create `~/.ssh/id_rsa` (your private key) and `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` (your public key) with the default length (generally `2048` bytes). The permissions on your private key **must be** `0600` (e.g. `-rw-------`)

(**note:**, you can choose to generate an `ecdsa` type key if you need, but do not use `dsa` as use of `dsa` keys has been deprecated and their use is generally disabled by default on current versions of `openssh`)

In order to login without password to Server A, your public key must be copied to Server A **and** it must be appended to (or copied to if it is the first key) `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on Server A. The directory permissions for `~/.ssh` on Server A **must be** `0700` (e.g. `drwx------`)

(**note:** the other file permissions can be `0644`)

The easiest way to get this all done from Server B is, after generating your key, is to `scp` (or `rsync`) your public key to Server A, either directly as `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` if you have no other keys on Server A, or by copying your public key to Server A and using `cat` and redirection (in append, not truncate/replace, mode) add your public key to the existing `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file there, e.g.

**If you have NO other public keys on Server A**

```
scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub Server_A:~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

**If you are Adding to existing `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on Server A**

```
scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub Server_A:~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.B
ssh Server_A "cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.B >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

(**note:** that `".B"` was appended to the public key name when copying to Server A *to prevent overwriting any existing `id_rsa.pub` on Server A*. You can now delete `~/.ssh/id_pub.rsa.B` on Server A -- it is now in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`)

That's it. Now `ssh Server_A` from Server B should work without a password. (everything that relies on `ssh` works without a password between Server B and A as well, e.g. `scp`, `rsync`, etc...)  If you have any problems, use `ssh -vv Server_A` to get debugging output of where the authentication fails.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is

`$ scp <path to local file> <server address:server path>`

or you can use
`$ put <path to local file> <server address: server path>`

Comment: I tried both but they didn't work, when I tried scp I got this "This service allows sftp connections only".

Comment: @Arun see [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-enable-sftp-without-shell-access-on-centos-7)